# Can i remapped bad block on Live RHEL5 system using following command

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

I am getting following disk error on one of my server

```
smartd[4235]: Device: /dev/sda, 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

Can i apply following command to repair bad block on live RHEL5 system .

```
badblocks -n -v /dev/hda1
```

Answer (score 1):

No.
badblocks only SEARCHES for bad blocks on drive. it does not repairs them.
for repair, you can use following commands:

> badblocks /dev/sda1 > badblocks_list
>
> fsck -t ext3 -l badblocks_list /dev/sda1

the first command saves the list of bad blocks in a file,which is feeded to fsck to repair.